# How to replace specific values that starts with some pattern in config.yml using sed

Tags: sed, yaml

I have a file named config.yml, I want to replace all the values in YAML file which start with keyword `config` only

```
key1: "config/some_text"
key2: "some_text/config/"
```

I want it like

```
key1: "my_new_text/some_text"
key2: "some_text/config/"
```

I'm using the following command, this might be wrong as I'm not familiar with regex

```
sed -i 's:config/*$.:new_text:g' file_name
```

and the output is

```
key1: "my_new_text"
key2: "some_text/my_new_text"
```

Comment: By doing so it was also replacing the values in key2 but I want to change the value only in key1

Comment: Why not `sed -E 's/^([^:]*:\s*)"config.*"/\1"my_new_text"/' file`?

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed 's:"config/.*:"my_new_text":' file
key1: "my_new_text"
key2: "some_text/config"
```

Comment: If for example key1: "config/some_text", but what if I want to change only config key, so my new key1: "new_value/some_text"

Comment: Change the regexp to only match what you want to replace - `s:"config/:"new_value/:`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sed -i -E 's/config[^"]+/my_new_text/' config.yml
```

Input:

```
key1: "config/some_text"
key2: "some_text/config"
```

Output:

```
key1: "my_new_text"
key2: "some_text/config"
```

Explanation:

- `-E` will use extended regex
- `config[^"]+` means "substitute `config` and the chars that follow if they are not `"` and they are at least one", so the second config will not be substituted because it doesn't have a char that is not `"` after it.

Comment: so what if, key2 will be in the following form
key2: "some_text/config/". In this case, it might fail I guess, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: No, you're not wrong. What is the difference between a "good" config and a bad one? The good ones don't have `"` before?